# Does $\sigma$ commute with pullback.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> **Question.** Let $X$ be a set and $T:X\to X$ be a surjective map. Let $\mathcal F$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Is it true that
>   $$\sigma(T^{-1}\mathcal F) = T^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F))$$

(Here $\sigma(\mathcal F)$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal F$, $T^{-1}(\mathcal F)=\{T^{-1}F:F\in \mathcal F\}$ etc).

It is clear that the LHS above is contained in the RHS. This is because the RHS is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $T^{-1}\mathcal F$.

I am able to prove the reverse containment under the additional assumption that $T$ be bijective.

To do this, let us write $\Sigma_{\mathcal C}$ to denote the collection of all the $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ which contain a given collection of subsets $\mathcal C$ of $X$. Then we have a natural map $\Sigma_{\mathcal C}\to \Sigma_{T^{-1}\mathcal C}$ which takes $\mathcal A\in \Sigma_{\mathcal C}$ to $T^{-1}\mathcal A$ and another natural map $\Sigma_{T^{-1}\mathcal C}\to \Sigma_{\mathcal C}$ which is the inverse of the previous map.
The equivalence follows because $\sigma(\mathcal F)=\bigcap \Sigma_{\mathcal F}$ and thus $T^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F))= \bigcap T^{-1}\Sigma_{\mathcal F}=\bigcap\Sigma_{T^{-1}\mathcal F} = \sigma(T^{-1}\mathcal F)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\{A\in \sigma (\mathcal F): T^{-1}(A) \in \sigma (T^{-1} (\mathcal F))\}$. Verify that this is a sigma algebra which contains $\mathcal F$. Hence it contains $\sigma (\mathcal F)$ which proves the equality without any extra assumptions on $T$.

Comment: +1 very nice...

Comment: So we don't even need $T$ to be surjective? That is very nice!

Comment: @caffeinemachine The moral here is: inverse images behave very well w.r.t. set theoretic operations, hence w.r.t. sigma algebras.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes Prof. Murthy. In fact this is what prompted me to conjecture this in the first place. Somehow I missed considering the set you considered. In hindsight it is natural. I learnt an important lesson from your solution(s). Thank you.